# Passing variable to promise in a loop

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a promise in a loop, and I don't know how to pass some scope variables into the promise handler.

```
for(var i in superarray){
    MyService.get(superarray[i].externalID).then(function(r){
        console.debug(i);
});
```

MyService is a working service, with a get method that return a promise.

```
app.factory('MyService', function($http,$q) {
  return {
     get : function(itemID){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/someresturl/'+itemID).then(function(e) { 
                deferred.resolve(e.data);
        }, function(reason) {
                deferred.reject(reason);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```

In my console, the console.debug logicaly doesn't display 1,2,3,4,5. But 5,5,5,5,5. (there are 5 elements in my superarray).

How can I pass 'i' value in my promise scope, so I can use it in the then() ?

Is it possible?

Comment: Someone should point out to you that your "get" function is needlessly complicated.  It could be replaced with: get: function(itemID) { return $http.get('/someresturl/'+itemID); }

Answer (score 80, accepted):

One way is to capture `i` in a closure :

```
for(var i in superarray) {
    (function(i) {
        MyService.get(superarray[i].externalID).then(function(r) {
            console.debug(i);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Another way would be to arrange for `itemID` to be repeated back as a property of `r` :

```
for(var i in superarray){
    MyService.get(superarray[i].externalID).then(function(r) {
        console.debug(r.itemID);
    });
};
```

Comment: Any link where I can get the syntax of (function(i){})(i); detailed ?

Comment: @Cooluhuru: You're just making an anonymous function (the `function(i) {}` bit) and calling it with `i` as the first argument. You end up shadowing the `i` from the outer scope, so you sort of pass `i` by value, not by reference.

Comment: There's loads of really scary stuff out there on the subject that would put you off. Blender's explanation is about as concise as it gets without leaving anything out. [This](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) is a very friendly intro to the subject.

Comment: second example won't work because i increases synchorously, but service async, so you end up with with only 1 resolved promise, and limit of i. But first one works as expected, many thanks!

Comment: One of the only times defining an anonymous function in a loop is a decent idea.

Comment: What about es6?  Is this issue fixed?

Comment: declaring functions inside of a loop won't pass jshint.

Answer (score 15):

By the time your callback is run, `i` will refer to the last element in your array. You can use a closure and capture the current value of `i`:

```
for (var i in superarray){
    (function(j) {
        MyService.get(superarray[j].externalID).then(function(r) {
            console.debug(j);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify the code a bit by using the built-in `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
superarray.forEach(function (item, index) {
    MyService.get(item.externalID).then(function(r) {
        console.debug(index);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I would have just commented on the accepted solution but I don't currently have enough reputation.

I think that the second solution of repeating the itemID back as a property of r would work just fine as well.

simple promise handler:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).run(['MyService', function(MyService) {
  superarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];


  for(var i in superarray) {
    MyService.get(superarray[i]).then(function(returned) {
      console.log(returned.id);
    });
  }

}]);
```

MyService returning itemID as a property of the returned object:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('MyService', function($http,$q) {
  return {
     get : function(itemID){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('www.google.com').then(function(e) { 
                var returnObject = {
                  'data': e.data,
                  'id': itemID
                };
                deferred.resolve(returnObject);
        }, function(reason) {
                deferred.resolve(reason);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}});
```

Here is a working example [on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FnLjoBfs7USyLLtDU2mx?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, I've used $q.all and I've added my parameter in array.
It worked

```
   for(var i in superarray){
      $q.all([MyService.get(superarray[i].externalID), i]).then(function(results){
        var r = results[0];
        var i = results[1];
        console.debug(i);
      });
    }
```