# How to pass a variable from view to scope using ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm making a browse page where users can see the top terms for my site's search facets (I'm using ElasticSearch/Tire.) I created an array of objects with a title and arguments in the format I need for search. I want to iterate through the array and display the title and then the results of my search for each facet. At first I tried using a for loop in the controller to iterate through `facet_selections`, but that didn't seem like the Angular way. So now I'm trying to use ng-repeat for the iteration, but I'm not sure how to pass the arguments from the view to the controller. I read through all the directives, and I don't see a good fit, which makes me think I might be on the wrong path all together.

Here is a simplified controller:

```
$scope.facet_selections=[{name:"Collection", value: "collection_title", term: "collectionTitle"}, {name:"Series", value: "series_title", term: "seriesTitle"},  {name:"Episode", value: "episode_title", term: "episodeTitle"},];

$scope.frequency=Frequency.query({facet: facet}).then(function(data) {
    $scope.topterms=data.facets[term].terms;
})
```

And here's the html:

```
<div class="browse" ng-repeat="object in facet_selections" ng-init="var term={{object.term}}">
    <h4> {{object.name}} </h4>
    <ul>
        <li  ng-repeat="term in topterms"> {{term.term}} ({{term.count}})</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What argument are you trying to pass?

Comment: I'm trying to pass `facet` (facet_selections.value) and `term` (facet_selections.term) into $scope.frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't bind the html to a promise. You have to wait for the promise to resolve then update the scope. So I would handle the initial loop in the controller, not with an `ng-repeat`.

```
$scope.facet_selections=[{name:"Collection", value: "collection_title", term: "collectionTitle"}, {name:"Series", value: "series_title", term: "seriesTitle"},  {name:"Episode", value: "episode_title", term: "episodeTitle"},];

for(var i; i < $scope.facet_selections.length; i++){
   var selection = $scope.facet_selections[i];
   Frequency.query({facet: selection.value}).then(function(data) {
        $scope.facet_selections[i].results = data.facets[selection.term].terms;
        $scope.$digest() // hook into the angular binding system
   });
}
```

then

```
<div class="browse" ng-repeat="facet in facet_selections">
    <h4> {{facet.name}} </h4>
    <ul>
        <li  ng-repeat="term in facet.results"> {{term.term}} ({{term.count}})</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

Passing arguments from the view to the controller is extremely easy:

```
$scope.numbers = [0, 4, 5, 2];
$scope.getTimesTwo = function(num){
    return num * 2;
};
```

then

```
<div ng-repeat="num in numbers">
    {{num}} <span>{{getTimesTwo(num)}}</span>
</div>
```

will result in

```
<div ng-repeat="num in numbers">
    0 <span>0</span>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="num in numbers">
    4 <span>8</span>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="num in numbers">
    5 <span>10</span>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="num in numbers">
    2 <span>4</span>
</div>
```

Its just that that is not really your problem, its promise resolution hooking to the `$digest` cycle

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful, and I think it's close to working.  How is `$scope.facet_selections[i].results` supposed to work? I thought that you might have meant `$scope.facet_selections[i].value.results` so that it creates a new scope like so `$scope.collection_title.results`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: with `$scope.facet_selections[i].results` I was just arbitrarily attaching the results to the `$scope.facet_selections` to make my life easier. `value.results` is also fine. I have no idea what `$scope.collection_title` is, so I can't comment on that. If you found this helpful, how about an upvote?

Comment: Apparently I don't yet have enough points for upvotes, but I'll happily do the green check once I've got this sorted. I'm returning results, but they're all for the final object in `facet_selections`. It seems like I might need to give them unique variable names.

Comment: Sure, unique variables would be another way to accomplish this.

Comment: Update, I ended up combining Fresheyeball's suggestions with an anonymous function ([suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244614/promise-in-a-loop)) to get this to work.